# Geoserver transaction send null date value

Tags: geoserver

I have a timestamp column in my postgis table, I send data to postgis using geoserver and wmts. I need to send a null value to the timestamp table sometime but I dont know how to do it. Is it possible to send a null value in the transaction? 
I have tried to send null or just leaving it blank, but neither seem to work.

Any ideas?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse dateTime NULL at:NULL

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse dateTime undefined at:undefined

Answer (score 3):

Try to omit the attribute altoghether. Or you can use the official XML way to specify something is null, that is add the xsi:nil="true" attribute:

`<ns:myAttribute xsi:nil="true"/>`

Not sure if GeoServer will understand it though, never tried to use it.

Comment: Yeah it works if I omit the timestamp from the postData request, writing a script that change the PostData request dependent on another input value. Will be the option if I cant send a null value

Comment: Updated the response with another possible approach.